# Is “fortnight” an outdated word?

Tags: word-usage

I'm studying English vocabulary books, I find this word in each unit describing time words (days, weeks, months...).

> There are 2 weeks in a **fortnight**.

Almost I haven't seen this word before in social websites, emails or movies. the only place I heard this word is in historical movies.

So, is it a outdated word or native speakers still use it?

[Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fortnight%2C%20two%20weeks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfortnight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20weeks%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Fortnight" is very much alive and well in British English.

I believe that many Americans regard it as a word out of history.

I suspect (though I don't know for sure) that other English speakers areas (eg Australia, New Zealand, South Africa) still use it.

**Update**: on GloWbE (the corpus of Global Web-based English, these are the figures:

- UK: 2900
- Australia: 1437
- Ireland: 784
- India: 661
- New Zealand: 571
- USA: 328
- Sri Lanka: 207

(The other 13 areas it distinguishes are all below 200, including South Africa and Canada).

Comment: Yes, in the US it's somewhat obscure and unusual.  People might understand it, but using it will immediately mark you as "not from around here."

Comment: I'm not even sure how many of us Americans even know what it means.  This is actually the crux of a Demetri Martin joke, "I like when good things happen to me, but I wait two weeks to tell anyone because I like to use the word 'fortnight.'"

Comment: @Andrew - Yeah, that's why I said "might understand".  Sadly, I am rarely disappointed when I underestimate what people are going to understand...

Comment: Saw a TV show once where the company is going broke and having difficulty paying the employees. At one point one of the employees says to the boss, "We all promised that we would stay on for a fortnight, but we've decided to stay on indefinitely, because none of us is exactly sure how long a fortnight is."

Comment: I have never heard a speaker of AmE use the term **fortnight** unselfconsciously, as part of their normal working vocabulary, when speaking to other Americans.

Comment: That 328 for the USA must be all references to ancient documents or quotations of non-Americans.

Answer (score 2):

> fortnight

is still often used in BrE, certainly more so than in AmE.

Answer (score 0):

Fortnight is still very much used in New Zealand English although it seems that it has mostly fallen out of use in the US (and maybe Canadian?) English. It is especially used in the form 'fortnightly', largely due to the most common frequencies of how companies pay their workers here. The 3 most common frequencies of getting paid are either weekly, fortnightly or monthly.

Now, I'm actually interested in how Americans express the same idea. If you get paid fortnightly, do you say you get paid 'every two weeks' or 'biweekly'? Or does this frequency of being paid not exist in America?

Comment: If you ask a question as part of your answer you are unlikely to get any interesting answers as people cannot answer an answer only a new question.

Comment: I did not ask a question as part of my answer. My answer was contained within the first paragraph and can be taken as a full and complete answer. Anyone with common sense can see that. My question was obviously an addition to my reply. If no one gives me "interesting answers" then that says more about people on this forum than it does me.